# Interceptors implementation in Struts 1

Tags: logging, reflection, interceptor, struts-1

I have to implement interceptor for logging via reflection in struts 1. 
Interceptors appeared in Struts 2 and there is no interceptors in struts 1, but there are some ways to implement such behaviour. I found 2 ways:

1. Struts Action Invocation Framework (SAIF): 
   http://struts.sourceforge.net/saif/#interceptor-class
   But there is very few information about it.
2. AOP (aspects: org.aspectj)

What is the best way to solve this problem? Is there any other ways?

Comment: maybe you can write filter in your web.xml. This will pretty much same behaviour as Interceptors.

Comment: I think it's not actually what I need, because filters perform some functionality before some actions, but I have to log this actions

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I didn't notice how old this question was, sorry.

Well, if you weren't using Struts 1 I'd recommend the Spring framework for this.  If you want to use the (not so old) version of Spring (3.2.9), it does work with Struts 1, though. While you're at it, check out Spring MVC :)

Spring has excellent AOP support as most of its "magic" is performed with AOP.

Here's an example of a logger that logs method entries and exits:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="loggingAdvisor"
        pointcut="execution(public * com.example.*(..))" />
</aop:config>
<bean id="loggingAdvisor"
    class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
    <property name="loggerName" value="logger-name" />
    <property name="enterMessage" value="Entering $[methodName]($[arguments])" />
    <property name="exitMessage" value="Leaving $[methodName](): $[returnValue]" />
</bean>
```